# Select only part of a HTML page with jQuery's .post() method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a website that has a voting poll module. A poll controller accepts a vote via a `POST` request containing the poll ID and response ID as parameters to `http://example.com/poll`.

The site-wide template of this site features the current poll in the sidebar; its a simple form with the `action` attribute set to the aforementioned URL. I am, however, highjacking this with jQuery to submit poll votes asynchronously.

This is the function I have thus far:

```
$('form.poll').submit(function() {
    var form = this;
    var response = $('div.response', form);
    if ($('input:checked', form).length == 0) {
        response.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).html('<p class="error">Please select an option.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
        })
    }
    else {
        var action = $(form).attr('action');
        $.post(action, $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
            alert('Data loaded: ' + data);
        });
        $('fieldset', form).fadeOut('fast');
        response.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $(this).html('<p class="success">Vote successfully added.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

As you can see, it merely intercepts a form being submitted and then executes the `POST` using jQuery rather than a full page request, so the visitor never leaves the page they're on.

My problem is: the whole page's HTML comes back in the `$.post` response (the line with the `alert()` call). How can I pick out the content of the `#content` `<div>` tag of the HTML that is returned, to be used as a response in my poll form? The mark-up for the poll form is:

```
<form action="/poll" method="post" id="poll" class="poll"> 
  <h3>Poll</h3> 
  <p class="question">Who do you think will win the Lockdown main event?</p> 
  <div class="response"><!--//--></div> 
  <fieldset> 
    <input type="hidden" name="poll" value="1" /> 
    <ul class="options"> 
      <li><label for="option_1"><input type="radio" name="response" value="1" id="option_1" /> Mr Anderson</label></li> 
      <li><label for="option_2"><input type="radio" name="response" value="2" id="option_2" /> Rob Van Dam</label></li> 
      <li><label for="option_3"><input type="radio" name="response" value="3" id="option_3" /> Sting</label></li> 
    </ul> 
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote" class="button" /> 
  </fieldset> 
</form>
```

And I want to insert the response into the aptly-named `.response` `div` tag. Any help, pointers, or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to detect that it is an AJAX request server-side and only return the content you need, many frameworks have this built in but you could manually implement something similar by checking for the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header added by most major JS frameworks (including jQuery) when performing AJAX requests.

A rubbish example in PHP would be something along the lines of:

```
<?php if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest' ) : ?>
  <html>
    <head/>
    <body>
<?php endif ?>

      <p>Martin's form stuff!</p>

<?php if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest' ) : ?>
    </body>
  </html>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header isn't technically part of any specification, but it's at least fairly consistent. Other means of checking recommended as an alternative are passing along an additional GET/POST variable with your AJAX request and checking for the presence of that. Either way, bringing back a whole document when you only need part of it is a waste of bandwidth and time.

Answer (score 3):

```
// just to be sure that it's of dataType html already
var data = $(data).html(); 

// grab element's content
var content = $(data).find('#content').html();

alert(content);
```

Find working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/BSrk6/

Answer (score 0):

If data contains all the HTML, then this:

```
$(data).find("#content")
```

should give you access to just the #content div, I think. Not very nice as it needs to parse the entire HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with using `.find()`/`.filter()` on data return from an AJAX request so I have used the following method.

What you might want to do is apply the data to a new, hidden, temp element and then access it as usual from there.

```
$.post(action, $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
    // create the new element, might want to generate a unique / random name
    $('body').append('<div id="temp_element' style="display: none;"></div>');        
    // apply the response data to the temp element
    $('#temp_element').html(data);
    // Martin, did you mean #content... or #response as I have it here?
    // alert out only the element you need
    alert( $('#response', '#temp_element').html();
    // remove the temp element
    $('#temp_element').remove();
});
```